# Clean up database after JUnit test.

Tags: java, junit, dbunit

I have a unit test that inserts rows into the database, and I'd like DBUnit to automatically clean up those rows afterwards (DBUnit does not initially insert those rows - that's purely the responsibility of the code being tested).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Make your INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE queries transactional and roll them back when the test is done.

Comment: thanks for the solution but the commit logic is present in the function which contains the testable code, further I mock the DB using DB unit so I dont have the control of the commit in the test.

Answer (score 1):

If you use JUnit4, then you can declare a function with `@AfterClass` annotation: it will execute after all tests and you can remove all the rows you added in your tables.

In JUnit3, you don't have any equivalent, but you can override the `tearDown()` method, which will be executed after each test (equivalent of `@After` annotation in JUnit4).

Answer (score 1):

If you allocate external resources(file/DB) in a Before method you need to release them after the test runs. Annotating a public void method with @After causes that method to be run after the Test method. All @After methods are guaranteed to run even if a Before or Test method throws an exception. The @After methods declared in superclasses will be run after those of the current class.

Example shows file as resource but you can use it for your DB cleanup.

```
 public class Example {
    File output;
    @Before public void createOutputFile() {
          output= new File(...);
    }
    @Test public void something() {
          ...
    }
    @After public void deleteOutputFile() {
          output.delete();
    }
 }
```

Comment: So @Juned in your code lets assume i make a add operation into the database in the something() function and now how do i delete the inserted entry using DB unit in the @After??

Comment: @UdayReddy Write a delete query and execute the statement in the After function.